# My code is running but not inserting any value

Tags: vba, excel

I have this segment of code running while looping through files in an folder.
Code does run but, is not having any output on this segment.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
Set rng1 = Range("B15:E81,N15:O81")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 
.Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Value = rng1
End With
```

1. I'm using this segment of code to extract data from B15 to E81 & N15 to O 81 from all the excel workbook in the folder.
2. Upon copying range into variable, it will activate the workbook where this code lie
3. Select last entry from column E, Offset by 1 row
4. Input range variable to the next blank cell.

Appreciate all the help I could find. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add ".value" on the rng1

Comment: Do you need values of rng1 to be input in *ONE* column (column "E") or *MULTIPLE* columns (starting from column "E", e.g. "E","F","G","H","I","J")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lastRow As Range, rng1 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets(1).Range("B15:E81,N15:O81")
Set lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)

lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).Value = rng1.Value
```

Comment: Thanks. That saved me a lot of trouble. However, I wasn't able to copy N:O from the code. So i declare another range variable for it and mimic your code for it

Answer (score 1):

It is not working, because you have to refer to the same amount of cells. In your case here `.Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Value = rng1` you are refering to one cell on the left and many on the right.

If you change your line to:

`.Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Value = rng1.Cells(1, 1)`

It will show you the first cell correctly.
A clean way to increase your left range is to use `Resize()` as in the answer of @CallumDA.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `Copy` ? Then the target size does not have to be calculated.

```
dim target as range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   set target = .Range("E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row+1 )
end With
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B15:E81,N15:O81").Copy target
```

Comment: Can't do that. values from B:E have to be separated from N:O is possible